# Unable to run Scrapy code

Tags: django, python-2.7, scrapy

I have written the following code:

spiders.test.py code:

```
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
  from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
  from wscraper.items import WscraperItem


  class MySpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "ExampleSpider"
  allowed_domains = ["timeanddate.com"]
  start_urls = ["https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/"]

  def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       titles = hxs.select("/html/body/div[1]/div[8]/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody").extract()
    #for titles in titles:
        #title = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
        #link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
        print title
```

The code for scraper.items is:
          from scrapy.item import Item, Field

```
      class WscraperItem(Item):
      # define the fields for your item here like:
      # name = scrapy.Field()
      title = Field()
      pass
```

I'm getting the following error on running the command "scrapy crawl ExampleSpider":

```
      [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in 
   retry_url
   r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
   response = self._open(req, data)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
     raise URLError(err)
     URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
    [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
    [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET 
     https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/>
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, 
     in mustbe_deferred
      result = f(*args, **kw)  
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
     packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 41, in 
     download_request
      return handler(request, spider)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
      packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 44, in 
      download_request
      return agent.download_request(request)
      d = super(CachingThreadedResolver, self).getHostByName(name, timeout)
      File "/home/priyanka/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
      packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 276, in getHostByName
       timeoutDelay = sum(timeout)
       TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
       [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
       {'downloader/exception_count': 1,
      'downloader/exception_type_count/exceptions.TypeError': 1,
       'downloader/request_bytes': 228,
       'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
       'log_count/ERROR': 3,
       'log_count/INFO': 7,
      'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
      'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
```

Comment: could you please include `WebScraperItem` code in the post, most probably issues there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spider name has to be `str`, not `list`, so:

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "timeandzone"
```

otherwise Scrapy spider loader fails to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I had a compatibility issue.So, I installed Scrapy1.3.3 and this resolved the issue and yes as mentioned in the answer above spider name should be a string.